# Ideas about Finite Difference Method Applications

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

By using the finite difference method, we can calculate the finite difference coefficients. And we can construct a matrix $D$ such that multiplying a vector of $\mathbf{y}$ values would lead to a second order approximation of the First derivative for the given data.

If we define the two vectors $\mathbf{x}=[x_0, x_1,\ldots,x_N]^T$ and $\mathbf{y}=[y_0, y_1,\ldots,y_N]^T$  such that

$$\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x})$$

for some scalar function $f$,  we can find a matrix $D$ such that

$$
f'(\mathbf{x}) \approx D\mathbf{y}
$$

For example, if all points are evenly separated we can construct based on finite difference formula where $h$ is the difference between $x$
$$
D = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    -3 & 4 & & -1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & & -1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & -4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\times \frac{1}{2 h}
$$

However, I'm considering from another direction. If we already known the first derivative of a function $f(x)$ at some discrete points and wanted to solve for the discrete function itself. Suppose given $D$ and vector $\mathbf{y} = f'(\mathbf{x})$,  we can solve the linear algebra problem

$$
    D\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{y}
$$

for $\mathbf{f}\approx f(\bf{x})$. Is this idea reasonable? Will there be some issues if I use this idea to solve problems?

Comment: the main problem here is that $D$ is singular, so you cannot invert it to solve the system

Comment: You cannot determine $f$ from $f'$ alone. You can only determine $f$ up to an additive constant. If you specify $f$ at a single point, then you have a well-defined problem. Example: Given a continuous function $g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a real number $f_0$, find a differentiable function $f$ such that $f(0) = f_0$ and $f'(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. You can still use finite difference methods to approximate the solution of this problem and you will have a nonsingular matrix.